# numpy array access in condition extremely slower than condition with direct value

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

While making some optimization in my code, I noticed the following speed impacts.

It seems there is a very slow numpy array access inside the condition:

```
print(timeit("i = k[5,5]", setup="import numpy as np; k = np.ndarray((13,17), np.int8)", number=10000000))
print(timeit("i = k; -1 < i", setup="k = 2", number=10000000))
print(timeit("i = k[5,5]; -1 < i", setup="import numpy as np; k = np.ndarray((13,17), np.int8); k[5,5] = 2", number=10000000))
```

The Output is the following

```
1.7849165841960317
0.6219190885851991
24.763694140816604
```

My questions:

**1. Why does the third operation take so much longer than the first and the second? And is there a way to improve the performance at this point?**

I expected, that the complexity is somehow the addition of the first and the second case.

**2. Similar strange thing in the following case. Why is the conversion to boolean and the True/False check that much faster?**

```
print(timeit("not k[5,5]", setup="import numpy as np; k = np.ndarray((13,17), np.int8); k[5,5] = 0", number=10000000))
print(timeit("k[5,5] == 0", setup="import numpy as np; k = np.ndarray((13,17), np.int8); k[5,5] = 0", number=10000000))
```

with output:

```
1.711371619476168
23.579222465618702
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, nothing you've presented suggests there's anything slow about indexing, only about comparisons involving np.int8 (and presumably other types).  What makes you think array access is involved?

Comment: Part of the story is that comparing `numpy` numerical types, like `np.int8` or `np.int32` or what have you, to Python `int`s or `float`s or even two different kinds of `numpy` numbers is going to be slow. Compare: `timeit("1 == i", "import numpy as np; i = np.int32(1)")` to `timeit("j == i", "import numpy as np; i = np.int32(1); j = np.int32(5)")`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, that is the solution. I didn't realize, that I compare different types. Your example works like a charm. :)

@DSM I just misunderstood what is happening there. I thought the difference between `-1 < k[5,5]` and `-1 < 2` is only the array indexing.